# YouTube Streaming API lastUpdateTimeSeconds returning NULL

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-livestreaming-api

I am using the YouTube php streaming API to monitor the status of some streams and upon trying to get 'lastUpdateTimeSeconds' it returns null. I have gone through the whole process of streaming (thinking it might not update until you were live) from ready to complete and never received anything other than NULL.

I have the following code that gets the details of each broadcast and its associated stream and have double checked the code.

```
$broadcastsResponse = $youtube->liveBroadcasts->listLiveBroadcasts('id,snippet,status,contentDetails',
    array(
        'mine' => 'true',
        'maxResults' => '10',
    ));

$streamsResponse = $youtube->liveStreams->listLiveStreams('id,snippet,status',
    array(
        'mine' => 'true',
        'maxResults' => '10',
    ));


 foreach ($broadcastsResponse['items'] as $broadcastItem) {

      $program = new stdClass();
      $program->broadcast = new stdClass();
      $program->broadcast->id = $broadcastItem['id'];
      $program->broadcast->title = $broadcastItem['snippet']['title'];
      $program->broadcast->lifeCycleStatus = $broadcastItem['status']['lifeCycleStatus'];
      $program->broadcast->recordingStatus = $broadcastItem['status']['recordingStatus'];
      $program->broadcast->boundStreamId = $broadcastItem['contentDetails']['boundStreamId'];
      $program->broadcast->enableMonitorStream = $broadcastItem['contentDetails']['monitorStream']['enableMonitorStream'];

      $program->stream = new stdClass();
      $program->stream->id = false;
      $program->stream->title = "";
      $program->stream->streamStatus = "";
      $program->stream->healthStatus = "";
      $program->stream->lastUpdate = "";

      foreach($streamsResponse['items'] as $streamItem)
      {
          if ($streamItem['id'] == $program->broadcast->boundStreamId)
          {
                $program->stream->id = $streamItem['id'];
                $program->stream->title = $streamItem['snippet']['title'];
                $program->stream->streamStatus = $streamItem['status']['streamStatus'];
                $program->stream->healthStatus = $streamItem['status']['healthStatus']['status'];
                $program->stream->lastUpdate = $streamItem['status']['healthStatus']['lastUpdateTimeSeconds'];
                break;
          }
      }

    $json->data[] = $program;
  }
```

Everything seems to work except for `$program->stream->lastUpdate = $streamItem['status']['healthStatus']['lastUpdateTimeSeconds'];`

The docs state it should return a unix time stamp but i cant get it to do that.